# How to correctly render initial data from the server using client components?

Tags: next.js

What is the correct way to use Next.js 13 and App Router to load initial data fetched from an API in component using 'use client', so that with JavaScript disabled, you get an HTML page, and with JavaScript enabled, you have the additional capability to send another API request without refreshing the page?

For example, a product search engine where, upon the first visit, you get a list of products rendered on server side, but subsequent product searches are performed client-side through the API.

My temporary solution is to create two components, the first being a server-side component page.tsx that fetches the data and passes it to the client component _page.tsx. The client component _page.tsx handles API for refreshing and makes subsequent requests from the client side.

However, this solution doesn't seem quite appropriate, and I think there is a more correct way to do this.